# How to fix "Gradle 5.4 requires Java 8 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use Java 7"

Tags: android, github, intellij-idea

[image]

I use IntelliJ IDEA, and there is a problem message:

"Gradle 5.4 requires Java 8 or later to run. Your build is currently configured to use Java 7"

How to handle it?

Answer (score 5):

Change the [Gradle JVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDrKH.png) or the [Project JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMLfr.png). You can also use an older Gradle version if you want to stay on Java 7.

Comment: on v3.6 of Android Studio I don't see the Gradle JVM option

Answer (score 4):

Check JAVA_HOME. It might be set to Java 7.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME% for windows users.

Answer (score -2):

Resolved by:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to open **Project Structure**
2. Change JDK location to embedded JDK (See screenshot attached)

Apply this and run your app it will resolve this issue

[click to open screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYhaw.png)